# Cannot connect to oracle system DSN with crystal reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, odbc

I am getting the follow error when I try to connect to a Oracle system DSN through Crystal Reports. I can connect fine from the ODBC. I also read online that this could be because the path variable is not set to the oracle bin directory.. but I checked and it is in fact there. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an odbc connection in crystal to connect to your ORACLE instance?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the full Oracle client installed?  The full client is several hundred megs, and I've seen several companies try to trim it down by removing parts they think are unnecessary.

Also, for troubleshooting connection problems, you may want to start out by trying to connect using SQL*Plus on the command line isntead of ODBC.  Try: `sqlplus username/password@server`.  If SQL*Plus works then you know Oracle is setup correctly and the problem is very likely with your application.

Comment: Sql *Plus does work.. and it was the full client... I did find something that resolved this issue however.. see answer below. Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I thought that resolve my problem but I still get the error.. It is related to this post I made.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293628/unknown-database-connector-error-in-crystal-reports

When I use the Oracle connection string I get that error.. when I user the ODBC I get this error..