# Unknown Database Connector Error in Crystal Reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

Ok, I am probably just shooting air with this question.. but I have no idea what's happening and I have been banging my head against it for the last couple days.

I have a crystal report version 12.2.0.290... I built this report against an Oracle connection string (not ODBC as it was giving me errors to use a stored procedure as a data source). Anyway, so the report was connecting to the database fine.. and I was able to build the entire report.. refreshing data with every change I made etc.. Once I was finished.. I closed the crystal report. When I open the report again and try to refresh the data I get the error "Unknown Database Connector Error in Crystal Reports". I get this error when I try to run the report straight from crystal reports.. or from the .NET wrapper that we built for this report. I also get the same error when I run the report (in CR) from another machine. In fact I get this error just trying to connect to an any Oracle database from that report..

The really strange thing is that if I open another report that we built a while ago.. I can connect to the same exact data source from it and it I go to File -> Open and open the first report.. I can connect to the Oracle data source and the report runs fine.. I can reproduce this strange behavior at will.. I don't know what is going on.... and I have been staring at this problem for the longest while.. if anyone has any ideas I will be more than happy to try them out...

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using the latest [Oracel Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html)?

Comment: @Barry, thanks for your response. Please forgive my noob question.. How do you check what ODAC version you currently have installed? I couldn't find this online..

Answer (score 2):

This is The Resolution:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d2811b33-2c2c-43d1-af51-9c54e9ad7920/unknown-database-connector-error?forum=wpf

I've fixed the problem, I just needed those lines:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a stored procedure as your data source, make sure it RETURNS a RESULT SET.  Once I added a 'SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable', the error went away.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest [Oracle Data Access Components?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html)

How to check which version you are using:

- During installation of ODAC, consult the ODAC Installer screen.
- After installation, see the history.html file in your ODAC installation directiory.
- At design-time, select Oracle | About ODAC from the main menu of your IDE.
- At run-time, check the value of the OdacVersion and DACVersion constants.

<sub>Note: This was originally a comment but added as an answer after OP response on how to check for the version of ODAC</sub>